# How to execute a SELECT query from Snowflake JAVASCRIPT UDF

Tags: javascript, function, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I need to execute a select query from Snowflake UDF and assign to a variable.. Since am using variable i guess i can only use JAVASCRIPT UDF in snowflake like below..

But the select query inside Snowflake JAVASCRIPT UDF is returning NULL everytime...

Please advise..

```
create or replace function fun1()

returns float

language JAVASCRIPT

as

$$

var a

a=select * from emp where salary like '%100%' and empno=1

return a

$$
```

Comment: You cannot run a select statement in a Snowflake JavaScript UDF. You can write a SQL UDF, but this does not allow storing a result in a variable.

Comment: Exactly what @GregPavlik said  -- stored procedures can do this, but not the UDFs

Comment: If i do this in Stored procedure.. how to i call all my Stored Procedures from a select query.. becoz i need to write multiple stored procedures and call all the stored procedures from a select query with logics

Comment: I think you need to update your question with a better explanation and some data examples of what you are trying to achieve. Your code example makes no sense as the use of the variable adds nothing to the function and it’s not obvious why you think SELECT * would teturn a float, which is how you’ve defined your function

Answer (score 0):

Assuming below: You want to retrun salary of employee whose empno=1, you can write something like below:

```html
create or replace procedure Fun1()
   returns  RETURNS TABLE (id int, name varchar) 
   language javascript
 
   as
   $$

 
 var sql_command = "select salary from emp where salary like '%100%' and empno=1'";
 var result;
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sql_command} );
    var resultSet = stmt.execute();
    result=resultSet.next();
     return result;
  
$$;
```

If this is not the case, then you have to write TableUDf's to return the table data. You can use SQL Scripting as well.

Refer: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/resultsets.html#label-snowscript-resultsets-use-return-table